# Loop to save multiple separate files based on combobox filter items

Tags: excel, vba

In Excel VBA, I would like to create a loop that iterates through different each values in a combobox (the combobox applies filters to the file) and save as a separate file.

I want to write something along the lines of:

list = [a,b,c,d,e,f]

For Each iteration In list:
    Worksheets("Combobox_sheet").Range("B4") = iteration
    save as (iteration +"file_name"+"xls")

it should return something 6 files e.g. "afile_name.xls",bfile_name.xls" etc..

I am really unsure, i have tried the below

```
Each i In List

Worksheets("Combobox_sheet").Range("B4") = i

save_as = i + "file_name" + ".xls"

save_as.save
```

and:

```
Dim i As Integer 
For i = Worksheets("List").Range("E2") To` `Worksheets("List").Range("E8") Step 1

    ("Combobox_sheet").Range("B4").Value = i
    save_as = i + "file_name" + ".xls"
    save_as.Save
    Next i
```

Comment: Correct me if I'm understanding this incorrectly:  You have a working macro that applies an autofilter to a table based on the selection in a ComboBox, then you want to save the filtered table?  If so, why not use `.Save As`, or `.Move` and `.SaveAs`?

Comment: Hi @Cyril, yes I have a working macro autofilter and yes i would like to save the file based on selection within the ComboBox. Although its not just one table, its multiple sheets it applies to. I just googled the `move` and it just move the work sheet to a different location.. not sure how that would help

Comment: You can use `Sheets().Copy` to get each sheet into a separate workbook (while not removing the sheet from the source file), which can then be `.SaveAs`'d.  That would allow you to fulfill your request of *it should return something 6 files e.g. "afile_name.xls",bfile_name.xls" etc..*  Make sure you keep a variable for your primary workbook, and loop through the desired sheets performing that `.Copy` task, `.SaveAs`, and `.Close`, before looping to the next sheet

Answer (score 0):

Example code related to my comment

```
Dim sh as worksheet
For each sh in ThisWorkbook.worksheets
    if sh.name <> "a name of a sheet to avoid" then
        sh.copy
        ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs "filepath/filename.xls", fileformat:=57 '57 is for xls files
        Activeworkbook.close
    end if
next
```

Comment: Hi @Cyril this will just save a copy of the workbook (sheet by sheet)?

Comment: @samc As written, this will create a copy of the sheet and put it in a new workbook. (try it with a workbook where your only code is `sheets(1).copy`).  This is the quickest way I know to get a sheet into a new workbook while not affecting the source workbook (`hence .copy` instead of `.move`).